# cannot agregate in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a service with logs in elasticsearch. I want to get users who have used my service.
Detailed log lines were returned on my request, but I want to get a unique "kubernetes.pod_name":

```
{
    "size": 10000,
    "_source": ["kubernetes.pod_name"],
    "query": {"bool": {"filter": [
        {"match": {"kubernetes.labels.app" : "jupyterhub"}},
        {"match_phrase": {"log": "200 GET"}}
    ]}},
    "aggs": {"pods": {"terms": {"field": "kubernetes.pod_name"}}}
}
```

why aren't the log lines grouped in the "aggs" section? What to do to get unique users?

Upd:
my query return:

```
{'took': 614,
 'timed_out': False,
 '_shards': {'total': 5, 'successful': 5, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0},
 'hits': {'total': 17703,
  'max_score': 0.0,
  'hits': [{'_index': 'dwh-dev-2020-10-14',
    '_type': 'container_log',
    '_id': 'vQ6vJHUBU_u817onY-cZ',
    '_score': 0.0,
    '_source': {'kubernetes': {'pod_name': 'jupyter-lyisova-2evg'}}},
   {'_index': 'dwh-dev-2020-10-14',
    '_type': 'container_log',
    '_id': 'xA6vJHUBU_u817onY-cZ',
    '_score': 0.0,
    '_source': {'kubernetes': {'pod_name': 'jupyter-lyisova-2evg'}}},
   {'_index': 'dwh-dev-2020-10-14',
    '_type': 'container_log',
    '_id': '6g6vJHUBU_u817onY-cZ',
    '_score': 0.0,
    '_source': {'kubernetes': {'pod_name': 'jupyter-bogdanov'}}},
  ...
```

I want to get 20 lines instead of 17703 where each line corresponds to a unique "kubernetes.pod_name"

Comment: I was inattentive. grouped values ​​are present in the aggregation section

Answer (score 1):

You can merge between [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) and [filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html)

```
{
      "aggs": {
        "labels_filter": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "match": {
                "kubernetes.labels.app": "jupyterhub"
              }
            },
            {
              "match_phrase": {
                "log": "200 GET"
              }
            }
          ],
          "aggs": {
            "pods": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "kubernetes.pod_name"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: with your query i can see all log lines without filtering and grouping applied

Comment: @S.Max can you please share some sample data and your expected search result ?

Comment: added the result to the question